# Capturing the mouse pointer in a particular window in x11

Tags: c, window, mouseevent, x11

I am able to obtain the list of all windows using `_NET_CLIENT_LIST` Atom property of x11. Using that, I choose a particular window of my interest, say the gedit window, and use `XSetInputFocus` and that will  perfectly set the keyboard inputs and controls to the gedit window.

Now my question is, is there a similar function in X11 such that we can set the mouse focus to a particular window, such that any mouse clicks or selections will be confined to that particular window only.

I tried `XGrabPointer`, but with no success. It will simply freeze the mouse and no further mouse inputs will  be displayed on screen (like mouse clicks; I can just see the mouse pointer, I can also move it, but it doesn't perform any click operations).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to poll for mouse events and, if the user tries to move out of the rectangle you should be able to reposition it.  If you don't keep the pointer out of the other window(s), I don't think you can prevent mouse clicks from reaching them, but that may be possible.